# mapping from multiple assemblies

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an assembly for mapping in nhibernate. some of the mapping classes in the assembly has reference in another assembly. how to configure mapping with reference to second assembly. I dont want to map the whole of the second assembly

```
  Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.SetInterceptor(new NHInterceptor());
        cfg.Configure(sessionFactoryConfigPath);



        FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure(cfg)
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                m.FluentMappings
                     .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("someassembly"))
                     .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always(),
                                      OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.All()),
                                      DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue(),
                                      DynamicInsert.AlwaysFalse(),
                                      DefaultCascade.None()
                                     )
                     .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<"someDateconventionobject">()
                     ;
            });
```

Comment: Can anyone help with these please.

Comment: Which mapping (automapping with Fluent NHibernate, "normal" mapping with Fluent NHibernate, mapping-by-code with NHibernate only)? Which versions of NHibernate (and Fluent NHibernate if used)?

Comment: normal mapping with fluent nhibernate 2.0

Comment: @cremor someassembly above has some reference mapping in other assembly.actually i am creating light weight mini session for the second assembly mapping which is a huge one

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a single mapping class:

```
m.FluentMappings
    .Add<MappingClassFromOtherAssembly>()
```

Or use the `Add(Type type)` overload and `Type.GetType(string typeName)` method if you don't have a reference to the other assembly.

Comment: but it would map the whole class map of the second assembly wouldnt it? is it the typename of mapping class

Comment: can anyone please help with these. i dont wanna add class map selectively from second assembly. i want the reference to added automatically if the need be

Comment: @arjun Do I understand you correctly that you want to add all mapping classes of assembly A and those of assembly B that are referenced by A? But you don't want to add the ones from B one by one? I don't think that this is possible.